# Substitute specific matches using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to execute substitutions using regex, not for all matches but only for specific ones. However, `re.sub` substitutes for all matches. How can I do this?

Here is an example.
Say, I have a string with the following content:

```
FOO=foo1
BAR=bar1
FOO=foo2
BAR=bar2
BAR=bar3
```

What I want to do is this:

```
re.sub(r'^BAR', '#BAR', s, index=[1,2], flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

to get the below result.

```
FOO=foo1
BAR=bar1
FOO=foo2
#BAR=bar2
#BAR=bar3
```

Comment: what you mean by `index=[1,2]`? you meant that you want to match the second and third matches?

Comment: I guess he meant if my matches are in a list L, apply changes to L[1] and L[2], but not L[0]

Comment: Yes, that's true. `index=[1,2]` indicates which ones should be replaced among the multiple matches out there. In this case, I want replace only second and third matches, and first (`index==0`) one should be left as is.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass replacement function to `re.sub` that keeps track of count and checks if the given index should be substituted:

```
import re

s = '''FOO=foo1
BAR=bar1
FOO=foo2
BAR=bar2
BAR=bar3'''

i = 0
index = {1, 2}

def repl(x):
    global i
    if i in index:
        res = '#' + x.group(0)
    else:
        res = x.group(0)

    i += 1
    return res

print re.sub(r'^BAR', repl, s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Output:

```
FOO=foo1
BAR=bar1
FOO=foo2
#BAR=bar2
#BAR=bar3
```

Comment: Great, it work! I didn't know that you can pass a function to the `repl` argument of `re.sub`...

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. Split your string using s.splitlines()
2. Iterate over the individual lines in a for loop
3. Track how many matches you have found so far
4. Only perform substitutions on those matches in the numerical ranges you want (e.g. matches 1 and 2)
5. And then join them back into a single string (if need be).

Comment: Ok, this will work...but looks unrefined. In addition, what if the pattern is more complex so that you can't split the matches with `\n`? Thanks anyway!